# Help with evaluating $E[XX^T]$

Tags: matrices, expectation

$X\in \mathbb{R}^n$,with mean $=\mu$, Cov $=\Sigma$. I've been trying to find $E[AXX^T]$ but I've quickly gotten stuck after reaching $AE[XX^T].$ I tried to see if I could do anything after expanding but I dont see where to go next. Any help is appreciated. (A is an $n\times n$ matrix by the way.)

$
AE[XX^T] = AE\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 x_1^2 & x_1x_2 & ... & x_1x_n \\
 x_2x_1 & x_2^2 & ... & x_2x_n \\
 ... & ... & ... & ... \\
 x_nx_1 & x_nx_2 & ... & x_n^2 \\
\end{array} 
\right)
$

Comment: Hint: $\mathbb Ex_ix_j=\text{Covar}(x_i,x_j)+\mathbb Ex_i\mathbb Ex_j$

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I reached what looked like the covariance matrix with $\mu ^2$ added to every element so after splitting it all up I've got $A(\Sigma +\mu ^2I)$ which looks like as far as I can take it

Comment: Based on the hint you find: $\mathbb E[AXX^T]=A(\Sigma+\mu\mu^T)$. Be aware that $\mu$ is a vector so $\mu^2$ does not make sense.